# Getting data by widget's name in monodev

Tags: c#, widget, monodevelop

I use monodeveloper 2.4.2.1 for windows.
My situation: I add boxes with widgets (Entry) to parent box in runtime. For identification I give names (property Name) to every widget. My question is how can I check if the entries are empty or not?

```
foreach(Container n in boxA.Children)
{
    foreach(Entry m in n)
    {
        here I want to check if anything is in Entry. n hasn't any property that
        can help me or I can't find it.
    }
}
```

Please tell me how to do this and what I did wrong.
Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (entry.Text))
    //do stuff
```